# How can I bring the desktop of another user on any TTY while me (unity running on TTY-7) and the other user are concurrently logged in?

Tags: lightdm, tty, xserver

Here is the link that i used for reference ...

https://journalxtra.com/linux/desktop/multiple-desktops-on-one-linux-pc-now-thats-greedy/

But sadly nothing seems to be working...
IS THIS A LIGHTDM PROBLEM!!!
EDITING THE CONFIGURATION FILE(lightdm.conf) HASN'T BEEN USEFULL(maybe i didn't do it correctly)

Comment: If you use lightdm, the first graphically logged in user will get TTY7, the next one get TTY8 and so on by default.

Comment: @ByteCommander :- Yes,indeed what u say is very true and supposed to happen...But no matter on what TTY(1-6) i start lightdm...the output still comes on TTY(7) DISPLACING the previous users desktop environment.So i m still stuck to just using one desktop environment.Thanks for answering!!!